# Cancellation of vacuum bubbles in the correlation function

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, greens-functions, correlation-functions

$$
G_K = \langle\Omega|T\prod_{i=1}^{2K}\phi(x_i)|\Omega\rangle.
$$

A problem sheet question asks you to *'Show that the contribution to $G_K$ of $O(λ_L)$, $L$ integer, in which all external points are connected to a single cluster contains no bubble diagrams.'*

But this isn't quite right is it? $G_K$ consists of 'connected diagrams' in the sense of having no vacuum bubbles, but not in the sense that all external fields are connected to one another via a single cluster. For example a 4 point function with no internal fields that looks like '| |' is 'connected' in this sense (although '| | o' is not') -- or am I mistaken?

Comment: What is $L$? Clearly given any fully connected diagram, I can add vacuum bubbles and that will increase $L$. PS, also please use MathJax.

Comment: What is $\lambda_L$? Connected can have many meanings. For instance, assuming $G_1=0$, one meaning of connected 4-point function is $G_{4,c}\equiv G_4 -G_2^2$. Is this what you mean?

Comment: I'm sure many people would like to answer this question, but can you please define what $L$ is? Does it have any relation to $K$? by $O(\lambda_L)$, I assume you mean $O(\lambda^L)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, you are right and the problem sheet is wrong. See [Timo Weigand's notes](https://www.thphys.uni-heidelberg.de/%7Eweigand/QFT2-14/SkriptQFT2.pdf) section 2.8, and specifically equation (2.145) which reads

> $$\left\langle \Omega \right| T \left\{\prod_i \phi(x_i) \right\}\left| \Omega \right\rangle = \sum (\text{all partially connected diagrams with } n \text{ external points}). $$